# PHP dropdown search bar with active links

Tags: php, html, sql

So i have a problem with search bar. the thing is i get my products from database and when i try to searach them the search bar only redirects to the produkti page. But it doesn't show what i am loking as a dropdown aand its not linkable.

```html
<?php 
include "header.php";

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "majsql", "registration");

if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
{
 if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
 {
  $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");
  if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id))
  {
   $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
   $item_array = array(
    'item_id'   => $_GET["id"],
    'item_name'   => $_POST["hidden_name"],
    'item_price'  => $_POST["hidden_price"],
    'item_quantity'  => $_POST["quantity"]
   );
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
  }
  else
  {
   echo '<script>alert("Izdelek je že bil dodan")</script>';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  $item_array = array(
   'item_id'   => $_GET["id"],
   'item_name'   => $_POST["hidden_name"],
   'item_price'  => $_POST["hidden_price"],
   'item_quantity'  => $_POST["quantity"]
  );
  $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;
 }
}

if(isset($_GET["action"]))
{
 if($_GET["action"] == "delete")
 {
  foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
  {
   if($values["item_id"] == $_GET["id"])
   {
    unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]);
    echo '<script>alert("Izdelek odstranjen")</script>';
    echo '<script>window.location="kosarica.php"</script>';
   }
  }
 }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
<form method="post" action="produkti.php">
   
   <input type="submit" name="manj300" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="pod 300€" />
   <input type="submit" name="nad300" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="nad 300€" />
   <input type="submit" name="vsi_izdelki" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="vsi izdelki" />
   
   
   </form>
</div>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br /><br />
   <?php
   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "majsql", "registration");
   $query ="SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY id ASC";
   if(isset($_POST["manj300"])){
   $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE price<=300 ORDER BY id ASC";
   }
   if(isset($_POST["nad300"])){
   $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE price>300 ORDER BY id ASC";
   }
   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {?>

       <div class="col-md-4">
    <form method="post" action="produkti.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
     <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:16px;" align="center">
      <img src="slike/<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" /><br />

      <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h4>

      <h4 class="text-danger">€ <?php echo $row["price"]; ?></h4>
      <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="form-control" />

      <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" />

      <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>" />

      <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Dodaj v košarico" />

     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
   <?php
    }
}
?>

   
   
   
   
   
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
   <br />
   
  </div>
 </div>
 <br />
 </body>
</html>

<?php
   include "footer.php";
?>
```

and in searchbar.php i have now

```html
<?php


$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration', $tbl_product);

if(!isset($_POST['Išči'])) {
 header("Location:produkti.php");
}

$search_sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE name LIKE '%".$_POST['Išči']."%'";
$search_query=mysql_query($search_sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($search_query) != 0)
{
 $search_rs =mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}

?>
```

the expected result is like when i write asus in search bar it dropdowns all asus products. And when i click on one of them it redirects me to his page in my example i have 3 products and the one with asus would be redirected to page p1.php .

Comment: If you make a mysqli connection, you cannot ( and should not ) be using mysql_ commands. So first thing to do is to fix that up.

Comment: can you please explain how? i am new to this

Comment: If I was you I would be running a browser and doing a search on mysqli. Is this your code or something you have copied?

Comment: this is my code

Comment: What, you knew how to use MySQLi functions in the first script you have shown us, but you forgot all about it when you wrote the second one …?

Comment: i have used a template and then modified it that my shopping cart works. I have done that with a help.

Comment: _“the search bar only redirects to the produkti page”_ - well both of the forms in the code you have shown have `action="produkti.php"` resp. `action="produkti.php?action=add&id=…"` - looks like you did not make any connection between your search bar form and the actual searchbar.php script at all yet.

Comment: the thing i have done in index is :<form action="searchbar.php" method="GET" >
  <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Išči tukaj">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Išči">
  </form>

Comment: Well then `$_POST['Išči']` appears not to be set, so you explicitly redirect back to your product page … `Išči` is the _value_ of the form element, not the _name_. The key in the $_POST array is the field name, not the value.

Comment: so i would need to modify my whole searchbar.php right?